# Returning child nodes of a particular type and their properties (Umbraco)

Tags: xslt, umbraco, nodes

I'm trying to write some XSLT which basically should go through the following algorithm:

```
if child of current node is of type Accordion
    if child of Accordion node is of type AccordionItem
        take the AccordionItem's title and content and display in <div> tags
    end if
end if
```

It seems pretty straight forward, but the code I currently have doesn't appear to be working as it should. I must be missing something, but I can't figure out exactly what. Here's my XSLT code so far:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::Home//AccordionItem[@isDoc]">
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3><a href='#'><xsl:value-of select="accordionItemTitle"/></a></h3>
        <div><xsl:value-of select="accordionItemContent" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why this wouldn't be working correctly? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your XPath isn't quite behaving as you've defined in your algorithm and is navigating to the node of type `Home`, is that intended?

If not, try modifying the XPath to the following:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/Accordion/AccordionItem[@isDoc]">
```

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something like that. Works perfectly, thank you very much!